# What does YACC output?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I have a lex program listed below, it recognizes (lexical analysis)specific tokens and outputs them to the screen when input from the keyboard.  I want to use yacc for syntactical analysis of the code below, but i don't quite get this part.....what would the output look like?  Is my code below sufficient?  I've read many articles online about yacc....just need someone to give a simple explanation.  Thanks in advance...

```
/* Regular Definitions */
RelationalOp_1         "<"
RelationalOp_2      "<="
RelationalOp_3      "=<"    
RelationalOp_4      "=="
RelationalOp_5      "!="
RelationalOp_6      ">"
RelationalOp_7      ">="
RelationalOp_8      "=>"

%%

{RelationalOp_1}        {printf("(RelationalOp_1, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_2}        {printf("(RelationalOp_2, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_3}        {printf("(RelationalOp_3, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_4}        {printf("(RelationalOp_4, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_5}        {printf("(RelationalOp_5, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_6}        {printf("(RelationalOp_6, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_7}        {printf("(RelationalOp_7, %s)\n", yytext);}
{RelationalOp_8}        {printf("(RelationalOp_8, %s)\n", yytext);}

.                            printf("Invalid input: %s\n",yytext);

%%

main()
{
  yylex();
}

yywrap()
{
}
```

Comment: This is just writing operation name and token ID while parsing the file, what you want to do?

Comment: After having learnt flex and yacc/bison, I just decided to roll my own parser.

Comment: Well when you start doing that and have a real question let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, what you have is incomplete for working with a yacc-generated parser.  In your lex-generated scanner, you want to provide tokens in memory to the parser, not simply write something to the console.

For understanding context, [Pete Jinks's lecture notes](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/ho/ho.html) are comprehensive, and show how lex- and yacc-generated programs work together.  You might also look at the online manual for [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html) , which is the GNU version of yacc.